# Как в SleepingOwl Admin добавлять '/' к пути загружаемой картинки?

Tags: php, laravel

В проекте используется SleepingOwl Admin. При загрузке изображения, нужно, чтобы в начало пути вставлялся '/'. Как это сделать?

Загрузка изображения происходит при помощи метода

`AdminFormElement::image(string $key, string $label = null): static`

Answer (score 0):

```
AdminFormElement::image('FIELD_NAME')->mutateValue(function ($value) {
    return \Illuminate\Support\Str::start($value, '/');
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Старайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы.